# Como abrir um projeto no Visual Studio baixado do Github?

Tags: visual-studio

Forkeei um projeto do Github e abri a pasta no Visual Studio, porém quando eu clico em iniciar projeto aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Não é possível iniciar o programa ponteiro invalido.

E mais, não tem o arquivo `.sln` na pasta, que eu baixei do git.

Comment: Talvez o mantenedor do projeto não quisesse prendê-lo ao Visual Studio, por isso não subiu o `.sln` junto com o resto do código. Com Java, eu evito subir coisas específicas da IDE, como o `.settings` do Eclipse. Acaba que a pessoa que baixa o projeto precisa aprender a configurá-lo "do zero" para poder usá-lo. Veja se seu caso não é análogo a esse que descrevi

Comment: Obrigado querido, informação relevantíssima ate o presente momento pois ainda sou noobinho :)